# Adding search functionality to android listview

Tags: android, listview, search

I basically want to add a simple search ability to my list view. Where there is a search bar at the top and the app sorts the searches for me. I would be greatful if anyone could help me. This is a perfect example of what I want: [Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/). Thanks!
PetActivity.java

```
public class PetActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pet_layout);
        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Pet[] items = {
                new Pet("1"),
                new Pet(""),
                new Pet(""),
                new Pet(""),
                new Pet(""),
        };

        ArrayAdapter<Pet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Pet>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Pet.java

```
package com.thebuildcast.cubeworldtoolbox;

public class Pet {
    private String name;


    public Pet(){
        super();
    }

    public Pet(String name){
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty vague question but these two links in the docs may help

[Search](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

[SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Also, I have used a `TextWatcher` to filter items in a DB or list based on the current `CharSeq` that was entered.

[TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Its hard to give a code example when the spectrum is so wide but these should be able to get you started on figuring out how you want to do it.

Comment: I want to do something like this: [Search Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) I just don't know how to get it to work with the way mine is set up.

Comment: You need to figure out if you're going to be able to use `SearchView` first or `EditText` with a `TextWatcher`. Then you need them in an object that you can search for a `String` such as an `Array`, `HashMap`, or DB